# Alter useMemo when write input in react testing library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm trying to do a test, in which when changing the input, I have to read the useMemo and change the disabled of my button, the userEvent is not making this change, has anyone gone through this?

I'm going to put part of my source code here, where the component and the test script are.

```
<>
  <input
    data-testid="ipt-email"
    value={form.email}
    onChange={(e) => {
      setForm({ ...form, email: e.target.value });
    }}
  />
  <button data-testid="submit-sendUser" disabled={isDisabled}>
    OK
  </button>
</>
```

This is my hook

```
const isDisabled = useMemo(() => {
  const { email } = form;
    
  if (!email.length) return true
  
  return false;
}, [form]);
```

Right after that is my unit test, where I write to the input and wait for the state to change

import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";

```
it("Should enable button when form is valid", async () => {
  const wrapper = render(<MyComponent />);

  const getEmail = wrapper.getByTestId("ipt-email");

  await userEvent.type(getEmail, 'example@example.com');

  const getBtnSubmit = wrapper.getByTestId("submit-sendUser");

  console.log(wrapper.container.innerHTML);

  expect(getBtnSubmit).not.toBeDisabled();
});
```

I can't make the input change reflect in the button hook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to [wait for changes](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/#waitfor) to occur after the action

```
 await waitFor(() => expect(getBtnSubmit).not.toBeDisabled())
```

moving code inside the handler [applieds to useEffect](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect#updating-state-based-on-props-or-state), but I feel its better to handle the validation inside the handler to so that code changes remain in one place.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

The combination of [fireEvents](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-events/) and forced move to the "next frame" worked for me

```
const tick = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, 0);
  });
};

// async test
fireEvent.change(getEmail, {target: {value: 'example@example.com'}})
await tick();
expect(getBtnSubmit).not.toBeDisabled();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your constant getEmail you get a component with a data-testid='ipt-name' instead of 'ipt-email' (but this is no longer relevant since the requester has modified his question...). The code below works for me :

my test :

```
import { render, screen, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
import App from './App';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';

it("Should enable button when form is valid", async () => {
  render(<App />);

  expect(screen.getByTestId("submit-sendUser")).toBeDisabled();

  const getEmail = screen.getByTestId("ipt-email");

  userEvent.type(getEmail, 'example@example.com');

  await waitFor(() => expect(screen.getByTestId("submit-sendUser")).not.toBeDisabled());
});
```

my component :

```
import React, { useMemo, useState } from "react";

export const App = () => {
  const [form, setForm] = useState({ email: '' });

  const isDisabled = useMemo(() => {
    const { email } = form;

    if (!email || !email.length) return true;

    return false;
  }, [form]);

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        data-testid="ipt-email"
        value={form.email}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setForm({ ...form, email: e.target.value });
        }}
      />
      <button data-testid="submit-sendUser" disabled={isDisabled}>
        OK
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```